# MySQL changes table title

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When i am making request to database using PreparedStatment, mysql adds "test." prefix to table title. For example... My database request method:

```
    public static ResultSet databaseRequest(String request, String ... args){
    try{
        if(connection != null){
            PreparedStatement prepState = connection.prepareStatement(request);
            for(int index = 0; index < args.length; index++){
                prepState.setString(index + 1, args[index]);
            }
            ResultSet result = prepState.executeQuery();
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Database connection had't been initialized");
        }
    } catch(SQLException exception){
        System.out.println("Error while requesting database: " + exception.getSQLState());
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How i use it:

```
ResultSet result = DatabaseUtils.databaseRequest("SELECT * FROM `table`");
```

Error - http://pastebin.com/Jxpi70Ea

How can i avoid it?

Comment: Hi. I have been out of using jdbc for ages, and i doubt itll fix the issue, but i believe you dont need single quotes around your table name. Single quotes sometimes cam be a cause of different behaviour

Comment: What is the name of the database you're using, it is `test`?

Comment: what is the the url you used to connect?

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb`

Comment: can you share the code where you creating the connection with db.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SHCbLv21

Comment: Definitely your connection url is getting messed up somewhere to set db as test. Please debug steps during connection creation and all places where db url is accesisble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connection url you should specify the initial database used as a default database. When default database is specifies you can use table names without database prefix.

> Initial Database for Connection
>
> If the database is not specified, the connection is made with no default database. In this case, either call the `setCatalog()` method on the Connection instance, or fully specify table names using the database name (that is, `SELECT dbname.tablename.colname FROM dbname.tablename...`) in your SQL. Opening a connection without specifying the database to use is generally only useful when building tools that work with multiple databases, such as GUI database managers.
>
> **Note**
>
> Always use the `Connection.setCatalog()` method to specify the desired database in JDBC applications, rather than the `USE database` statement.

Comment: But my database connection url is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb`, `maindb` is my database

Comment: Then the query should work as expected, the error is about another query and another database.